# no such file to load -- bcrypt_ext (via devise)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, bundler, bcrypt

I'm using database authentication in devise(current gem) on rails 3 and I get the following error when trying to log in with username/password.

```
no such file to load -- bcrypt_ext 

This error occurred while loading the following files:
   bcrypt
   bcrypt_ext
```

I have previously "Successfully installed bcrypt-ruby-2.1.2" gem.

Any ideas? I also tried giving bundler the git repo address and fetching the master, but it doesn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 11):

I had this problem as well.  When I installed the gem, the output told me

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1
```

so I assumed that it had, in fact, built native extensions.  But when I went hunting in .../gems/bcrypt-ruby-2.1.4/ext/mri I saw that it not appear to have built anything.

I manually went in and ran

```
cd [path to your gems folder]/gems/bcrypt-ruby-2.1.4/ext/mri
ruby extconf.rb
make
sudo make install
```

This did the trick for me.

Comment: This worked for me. I was getting the most random bcrypt error. Running rails server would work...then I would switch branches, switch back without making changes...and then rails server wouldn't work anymore saying can't find bcrypt. I followed this and now it works. thanks.

Comment: Had a similar problem while bundling the gems in a subdirectory of the passenger root.  This worked for me.

Comment: Same issue. How does one "make" and "make install" on windows 7 with dev kit installed?

Comment: I only voted this down because sudo make is 'nix command, and the issue is ruby.

Answer (score 8):

Do you have these in your Gemfile?

```
gem "bcrypt-ruby", :require => "bcrypt"
```

Also -- [this issue on devise](http://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/issue/527) might apply, check it out

Comment: Have this line in the Gemfile, still the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.

add in gemfile:

```
gem "bcrypt-ruby", '~> 3.0.0'
```

try bundle install and then bundle update bcrypt-ruby

Comment: I had to force mine down from 3.1.0 to 3.0.1 on Windows and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, i simply deleted the vendor directory and did bundle install.

Fixed the problem.  Maybe theres a problem in the make where it won't overwrite.

Comment: you can post it comment instead.

Answer (score 0):

Check out your Gemfile. See whether you have "bcrpyt-ruby" gem or not. If it is not there then  add "bcrpyt-ruby" gem.

```
gem "bcrypt-ruby", :require => "bcrypt"
```

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same issue, this resolved it-

```
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.9'
```