# Rails server stops working after (what I believe) is switching branches

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I'm working on my app and everything is great. All tests pass, app works beautifully. Then, I switch branches without making any changes, switch back, and get this error when I try to run "rails server" again. This has happened a few times now and I have no idea why.

```
/Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require': no such file to load -- bcrypt_ext (LoadError)
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `block in require'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `block in load_dependency'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:591:in `new_constants_in'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1/lib/bcrypt.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `block in require'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `block in load_dependency'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:591:in `new_constants_in'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/devise-1.4.9/lib/devise/models/database_authenticatable.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/devise-1.4.9/lib/devise/models.rb:60:in `const_get'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/devise-1.4.9/lib/devise/models.rb:60:in `block (2 levels) in devise'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/devise-1.4.9/lib/devise/models.rb:59:in `each'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/devise-1.4.9/lib/devise/models.rb:59:in `block in devise'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/devise-1.4.9/lib/devise/models.rb:86:in `devise_modules_hook!'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/devise-1.4.9/lib/devise/models.rb:58:in `devise'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/app/models/user.rb:16:in `<class:User>'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/app/models/user.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:454:in `load'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:454:in `block in load_file'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:591:in `new_constants_in'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:453:in `load_file'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:340:in `require_or_load'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:491:in `load_missing_constant'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:183:in `block in const_missing'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:181:in `each'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:181:in `const_missing'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/ext/module.rb:36:in `const_missing'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/app/admin/users.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:235:in `load'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:235:in `block in load'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `block in load_dependency'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:591:in `new_constants_in'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:235:in `load'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.3.2/lib/active_admin/application.rb:132:in `block in load!'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.3.2/lib/active_admin/application.rb:132:in `each'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.3.2/lib/active_admin/application.rb:132:in `load!'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.3.2/lib/active_admin/application.rb:155:in `routes'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.3.2/lib/active_admin.rb:63:in `routes'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/config/routes.rb:4:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:233:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:233:in `draw'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:235:in `load'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:235:in `block in load'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `block in load_dependency'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:591:in `new_constants_in'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:235:in `load'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:127:in `block in reload_routes!'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:127:in `each'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:127:in `reload_routes!'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:120:in `block in routes_reloader'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:32:in `call'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:32:in `execute_if_updated'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/railtie.rb:14:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:419:in `_run_prepare_callbacks'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:40:in `initialize'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:33:in `new'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:33:in `build'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:79:in `block in build'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:79:in `each'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:79:in `inject'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:79:in `build'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:162:in `app'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:35:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `run'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `each'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `run_initializers'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:134:in `initialize!'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `block in require'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `block in load_dependency'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:591:in `new_constants_in'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/config.ru:1:in `new'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:35:in `eval'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:35:in `parse_file'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.4/lib/rack/server.rb:162:in `app'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.4/lib/rack/server.rb:253:in `wrapped_app'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.4/lib/rack/server.rb:204:in `start'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:65:in `start'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:30:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `tap'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I think i've fixed this issue at least 4 times without actually knowing what is causing it or what i did to fix it...what is causing this?

Here is what I do to fix this issue:
1) Checkout the oldest commit I have in my current branch (called 'paperclip').
2) Do bundle install (which installs all gems into bundler/ for some reason)
3) Git add . and/or git stash to get rid of the changes I just made to the unnamed branch after checking out 
4) Checkout the initial branch again ('paperclip') and run rails server.
5) It works.

I have no idea what is causing this or what fixes it because seemingly i'm not doing anything for either case. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like 'bcrypt_ext' gem is not installed on your server!

Make sure to run `bundle install` after updating the source code, e.g. switching branches, or pulling new code revisions..

Comment: I have never used bcrypt_ext before and it was never needed. It works perfectly fine without it until I switch branches and then switch back (without making a single change). Then, to fix it, I basically have to reinstall my gem directory (by checking out an old enough branch that the gem directory isn't there anymore), installing it, and switching back. Again, no actual changes have been made! Also, tried bundle install WITH bcrypt and it did nothing.

Comment: PS. I tried something from another SOF answer: cd [path to your gems folder]/gems/bcrypt-ruby-2.1.4/ext/mri
ruby extconf.rb
make
sudo make install  which worked....any idea why? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900180/no-such-file-to-load-bcrypt-ext-via-devise)

Comment: you should probably also use different gemsets in RVM for each branch... 'rvm gemset help'

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why but this worked:

```
cd [path to your gems folder]/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1/ext/mri 
ruby extconf.rb 
make 
sudo make install
```

found here: [no such file to load -- bcrypt_ext (via devise)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900180/no-such-file-to-load-bcrypt-ext-via-devise)