# make.exe: GCC: Command not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, gcc, bcrypt

I'm trying to install BCRYPT... but I need to compile it.  I'm following the instructions from the 1st answer on this post

[no such file to load -- bcrypt_ext (via devise)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900180/no-such-file-to-load-bcrypt-ext-via-devise)

I am in the bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1-x86-mingw32\ext\mri> folder and typing

```
PS C:\Ruby200\lib\ruby\gems\2.0.0\gems\bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1-x86-mingw32\ext\mri> ruby .\extconf.rb
creating Makefile`
PS C:\Ruby200\lib\ruby\gems\2.0.0\gems\bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1-x86-mingw32\ext\mri> make
compiling bcrypt_ext.c
make.exe": gcc: Command not found
make.exe": *** [bcrypt_ext.o] Error 127
PS C:\Ruby200\lib\ruby\gems\2.0.0\gems\bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1-x86-mingw32\ext\mri>
```

I installed the devkit, added it to my path variables.

GCC is installed and recognized:

```
gcc --version
gcc.exe (rubenvb-4.7.2-release) 4.7.2

make --version
GNU Make 3.81

ruby --version
ruby 2.0.0p0 (2013-02-24) [i386-mingw32]
```

I don't understand why it is saying it can't find the command GCC when run in this instance.

Thank you so much for your help, I'm sure this is something simple.  I'm running Power Shell, windows 8, and using DevKit-mingw64-32-4.7.2-20130224-1151-sfx.exe which tested good

Comment: Is that GNU make? Is MinGW in path? Also see this: https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/issues/152. And if you're on 64 bit system, you should use mingw64-64-4.7.2.

Comment: It's the make from the devkit for 32 bit. MinGW is in my path as you can tell that gcc --version gives an output.  I'll give the 64 bit version a try, but I figure the 32 should work just fine.  Thanks for the information.

Comment: Also, when I install json from the devkit install guide, it compiles and works fine.  Could it be the makefile I'm creating from the guide?

Comment: The 64 Bit didn't help, in the makefile generated from ruby it has CC = gcc.  So I just don't understand why it isn't finding GCC when it's in my path and I can use it in a command prompt?

Comment: Anyone?  Still can't solve this one.

Comment: Did you try starting build from MinGW console?