# no such file to load -- bcrypt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bcrypt

I have installed bcrypt-ruby using

```
    gem install bcrypt
```

and

```
    sudo gem install bcrypt
```

(For some reason they both installed to different locations)

I then try and run

```
     require 'bcrypt'
```

and get

```
    no such file to load -- bcrypt
```

I am running Ruby on rails, Mac OS 10.6.8

Comment: This question might already be answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900180/no-such-file-to-load-bcrypt-ext-via-devise

Comment: The reason they install to different places when you use `sudo` is because `gem install ...` installs it just for your user but `sudo gem install ...` installs it for **all** users on the computer as **root**.

Answer (score 0):

put the

```
gem 'bcrypt-ruby'
```

in your Gemfile.

and do 'bundle install' at the root of your application