# Ruby bcrypt error - cannot load such file -- 2.1/bcrypt_ext

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I get this error pop up in my browser. Does anyone have any solutions for this problem?

> LoadError in ProductsController#index
>
> cannot load such file -- 2.1/bcrypt_ext

Comment: could you paste the whole error log please :)

Answer (score 1):

Modify your Gemfile Add -

```
gem 'bcrypt-ruby'
```

run

```
bundle install
```

Solution to Similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900180/no-such-file-to-load-bcrypt-ext-via-devise)